# Remove outbound unused namespaces from soap body message

Tags: web-services, soap, namespaces, cxf

I am using CXF JAXWS Client for retrieving some information from an external web services. So, basically, we have .xsd and .wsdl files from the external and try to implement our ws consumer by generating the client stubs using cxf-codegen-plugin. We cannot change the .xsd and .wsdl files. Everything works fine, we are able to send and retrieve soap messges from the external services. 
However, when I look into the soap request message from the log, I find a lot of unused namespaces in the soap (body) message sent from our ws client.
Below is an example

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:aheaderns="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/header.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    ...
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <ns7:requestQuery xmlns:ns15="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/AAA" xmlns:ns14="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/BBB" xmlns:ns13="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/DDD" xmlns:ns12="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/CCC" xmlns:ns11="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/EEE" xmlns:ns10="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/FFF" xmlns:ns9="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/GGG" xmlns:ns8="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/HHH" xmlns:ns7="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/III" xmlns:ns6="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/JJJ" xmlns:ns5="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/KKK">
        <ns7:sample>
            <ns7:type>A</ns7:type>
            <ns7:ref>1</ns7:ref>
        </ns7:sample>
    </ns7:requestQuery>
</soap:Body>
```

Is there any way to remove the unused namespaces from the outbound soap message sending from the client?

Answer (score 2):

You could move your client proxy classes to the same package and map it to the proposed namespace specified in the wsdl. 
Put this code into the package-info.java class:

```
@XmlSchema(xmlns = { @XmlNs(prefix = "ns1", namespaceURI = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx") }, 
            namespace = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx")
package clinet.sample.proxy;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try to see if this soluion works. However, I would prefer not changing any from the generated sources, since the process to build and deploy the war is nightly meaning that everynight the client stubs will be automatically generated and packed into jar and war. I cannot change the generated package-info.java because of this process. Is there another way of removing those duplicate namespaces?

Comment: You could set your package name in the `extraargs` of your `cxf-codegen-plugin` configuration in the `pom` file like this:

`<extraargs>           <extraarg>-p</extraarg>          <extraarg>clinet.sample.proxy</extraarg>         </extraargs>`

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I have tried changing the package-info class according to your recommendation, unfortunately, the duplicate namespaces still remain the same. If you may suggest me what is the root cause why the unused namespaces have been generated, I would appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: I think the types used in the server side belongs to the different packages and it causes generates multiple namespaces in the `wsdl` complex types definitions.

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this problem for quite sometime, I found the solution. However, I think my solution is not to solve the problem at the root cause but it works for now.

Basically, I use XSLTOutInterceptor from CXF to apply the XSL to the out message. However, the default PRE_STEAM phase is not working for me. Then, I decide to extend the XSLTOutInterceptor so as to change its PHASE to WRITE. So that, the unused namespaces will be removed during the writing of the protocol message before sending it out.

The XSL I use is from [how to remove unused namespaces from source xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593326/xsl-how-to-remove-unused-namespaces-from-source-xml)

By the way, I still have no idea why those unused namespaces have been generated. If anyone could give me a suggestion, I would appreciate it.

Thanks :)