# How to remove list of namespaces declarations using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

How to remove multiple specific namespaces declarations (usage doesn't matter) using `XSLT`?
**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.a.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.b.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.c.com" xmlns:ns4="http://www.d.com" xmlns:ns5="http://www.e.com">
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:a>
            <ns2:b>data1</ns2:b>
            <ns2:c>data2</ns2:c>
        </ns2:a>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

Need to remove: `ns4`, `ns5`.

**Required output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.a.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.b.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.c.com">
    <ns1:Body>
        <ns2:a>
            <ns2:b>data1</ns2:b>
            <ns2:c>data2</ns2:c>
        </ns2:a>
    </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

Thanx in advance!

UPD:

- need to remove namespaces based on the declared namespaces (e.g. `"http://www.d.com"`).
- XSLT v.1.0.

Comment: XSLT 1, 2 or 3? `ns4` or `ns5` is just a prefix, do you want to remove declarations based on the used prefix? Or based on the declared namespace e.g. `http://example.com`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSL - How to remove unused namespaces from source xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593326/xsl-how-to-remove-unused-namespaces-from-source-xml)

Comment: @Siebe Jongebloed no, i saw it. In my case unused items may remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove namespace nodes based on their URIs, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.='http://www.d.com' or .='http://www.e.com')]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```