# Remove unused namespaces from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove unused namespaces upon loading an XML file.

It might look like this:

```
<root xmlns:ns1="some_namespace" xmlns:foo="unused_namespace">
  <ns1:a>bla</ns1:a>
  <c xmlns="std_namespace">
    <d>text</d>
  </c>
  <ns2:e xmlns:ns2="another_ns">
    <ns2:f>aaa</ns2:f>
  </ns2:e>
</root>
```

and should be transformed to

```
<root xmlns:ns1="some_namespace">
  <ns1:a>bla</ns1:a>
  <c xmlns="std_namespace">
    <d>text</d>
  </c>
  <ns2:e xmlns:ns2="another_ns">
    <ns2:f>aaa</ns2:f>
  </ns2:e>
</root>
```

I need to use XLST 1.0 (Java).

I tried using the XLST from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594626

but it removes ALL namespace mentions, not only the unused ones.
I managed to modify it so that std-namespaces are kept, but the other used namespaces are removed.
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" priority="-2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:variable name="vtheElem" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
                <xsl:variable name="vPrefix" select="name()"/>
                <xsl:if test="
                ($vPrefix = '')
                or
                ($vtheElem/descendant::*
              [(namespace-uri()=current()
             and 
              substring-before(name(),':') = $vPrefix)
             or
              @*[substring-before(name(),':') = $vPrefix]
              ])
      ">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting XML (from example above)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <a>bla</a>
    <c xmlns="std_namespace">
        <d>text</d>
    </c>
    <e>
        <f>aaa</f>
    </e>
</root>
```

How can i modify the XSLT to preserve the used namespaces?

(i tried other answers - but they performed even worse than the one linked)

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <ns1:a xmlns:ns1="some_namespace">bla</ns1:a>
   <c xmlns="std_namespace">
      <d>text</d>
   </c>
   <ns2:e xmlns:ns2="another_ns">
      <ns2:f>aaa</ns2:f>
   </ns2:e>
</root>
```

which is semantically identical to the output you expect. The only difference, AFAICT, is the placement of the `xmlns:ns1` namespace declaration - which should not make any difference. But then neither should a redundant namespace declaration - so the purpose of this exercise remains unclear.